# MYSQL tried everything cannot login with created users. Root is only account that can login

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn and launch my own wordpress server. I was in the process of creating MYSQL database and created a database user, assigned the privileges to that account, set password and still cannot log in with it. I have tried to login through both phpmyadmin and CLI. I am trying to login through localhost, i am not allowing any remote connections as everything is run on my server.

the error i get is:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bsadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| bsadmin          | %         |
| bsadmin          | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for bsadmin@localhost                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'bsadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `brdgsol`.* TO 'bsadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'bsadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have flushed privs as well. I read the article similar to this but it does not state or atleast i do not see how it states that the account can login through localhost. It states about logging in from socket and network.
Please help.

Comment: Did you flush the privileges after adding them?

Comment: Did you flush the privileges?

Comment: i read that, the solution stated logging in from sockets and over network. I am access this account on localhost. I am assigning this account to just my wordpress site and want only this account to access this table for security reasons. I read that article and doesnt really tell me how two users can both login with local host.

Comment: Did you flush the privileges?

Comment: yes a few times

Comment: anyone else have some help i am stuck please assist.

Comment: Hey maybe it has to do with an anonymous user. I know about posting links but I have been searching for the issue for you and found this thread with the exact same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw